# SCCM - Collecting Local Admins Inventory

Tags: sccm, wmi

I am unable to collect data on the LocalAdmins group on computers. When I check the log files, I get the error below. I am not sure what I need to do in order to get this data? Is it an issue with the MOF file that I imported?

```
<![LOG[Collection: Class "Win32_LocalAdmins" does not
exist.]LOG]!><time="15:26:27.400-60" date="10-01-2019"
component="InventoryAgent" context="" type="2" thread="13564"
file="collectiontask.cpp:726">
```

Here is the MOF file:

```
[ SMS_Report (TRUE),
  SMS_Group_Name ("LocalAdmins"),
  SMS_Class_ID ("MICROSOFT|LocalAdmins|1.0"),
  Namespace ("root\\cimv2") ]
class Win32_LocalAdmins : SMS_Class_Template
{
    [SMS_Report (TRUE), key ] string Account;
    [SMS_Report (TRUE)      ] string Domain;
    [SMS_Report (TRUE), key ] string Name;
    [SMS_Report (TRUE)      ] string Type; 
};
```

Comment: Can you provide the query you're using in your MOF file?

Comment: Hi, I have added the MOF file data to the post.

Comment: Can you try BLefevre's solution from the thread below? https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/systemcenter/en-US/c5ebcdc9-3772-4f57-97b5-f05804ef844f/collecting-all-users-with-admin-rights-on-sccm?forum=configmgrgeneral Also, the most popular way to achieve that query seems to be from Sherry Kissinger: https://tcsmug.org/blogs/sherry-kissinger/244-all-members-of-all-local-groups-configmgr-2012

Comment: I modified the .mof file according to the article in the link and re-imported it. It doesn't seem to give an error in the InventoryAgent log, but if I try a query based on LocalUserAccounts then it still returns 0 results.

Comment: Sorry, I am actually getting the error still, but since I modified the MOF file and imported it, I now get: "Class "cm_LocalGroupMembers" does not exist.]LOG]!"